# How to get the Source of the Page in Protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using Protractor to run my Test and want to capture the source of the Whole Page for debugging purpose. Using Selenium WebDriver

How do i get the Source of the Page (content similar to View/Source when manually viewing it)

Comment: I've post solution for Angular app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51425252/1204375

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if you are looking for the source code of the page currently opened by driver, if Yes, you can use below method to get the source code.

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

To get the source of the page, the [Protractor documentation](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getPageSource) says to use the `getPageSource()` method. Remember it returns a Promise.

```
browser.get('http://www.example.com')
.then( function () {
    return browser.getPageSource();
.then( function (txt) {
    console.log(txt);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
browser.get('https://myapplication.abc.com/');
browser.getPageSource().then(function (res) {
  console.log('Page source code is-' + res);
});
```