# Expect text to be absent in pagesource-Protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, webdriver, protractor

I need to get the pagesource & then check whether the text "hello world" is absent in the pagesource.

I am trying the below method which is failing.

```
var page_source=browser.getPageSource().then(function (text){
    expect(text).not.toContain("hello world");
});
```

Any suggestions  ??

```
Error trace:
Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Protractor\Testcases\test.js:56:38)
        at C:\Protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:110:25
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1067:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2396:12)
        at schedulerExecute (C:\Protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2860:25)
        at C:\Protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 85.814 seconds


[18:02:43] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[18:02:43] I/launcher - internet explorerANY #01 failed 1 test(s)
[18:02:43] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[18:02:43] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

Specs file:
specs: ['./Testcases/test.js'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression way for your requirement.

Examples:

```
 it("The 'toMatch' matcher is for regular expressions", function() {
     var message = "foo bar baz";

     expect(message).toMatch(/bar/);
     expect(message).toMatch("bar");
     expect(message).not.toMatch(/quux/);
  });
```

**FYI** - toContain()- for finding an item in an Array.

Example:

```
 it("works for finding an item in an Array", function() {
     var a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

     expect(a).toContain("bar");
     expect(a).not.toContain("quux");
  });
```

Comment: var page_source=browser.getPageSource().then(function (text){
expect(text).not.toMatch("hello world");
});

Comment: Getting similar Failed expectation error while trying the workaround you mentioned for above snippet. Is it because i am using browser.getpagesource() ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an appropriate answer suited for the scenario mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of Suggestions.

1. You need not resolve the Promise. Jasmine expect does it for you

`expect(browser.getPageSource()).not.toContain("hello world")`

And yes, what you are doing is correct- The Rest of it - I mean the Jasmine assertion and use of `not` is correct and it should work as expected

Comment: Strangely it fails by this approach too & it keeps throwing me the "  Error: Failed expectation" failing the test.

Comment: Also can you confirm ... that you are using Jasmine and not Mocha ... Also .. it is Jamsmine2??

Comment: Using Jasmine2 along with Protractor5.

Comment: Can you post the complete error stack ... and also the spec file if possible.... the expect statement would  have thrown the complete proper error

Answer (score 0):

If you use app based on **Angular** you shuold do something *strange*.

Due to https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#how-to-disable-waiting-for-angular you should **disable waiting** for Angular itself.

Example:

```
describe('Google Site Verification', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
    });

    it('should be injected', () => {
        const source = browser.getPageSource();
        expect(source).toMatch(/google-site-verification/i);
    });
});
```